# How many parameters does the function StrStr require

Tags: installation, nsis

I am attempting to use the NSIS function `StrStr` but I get the following error:

`!insertmacro: macro "FUNCTION_STRING_StrStr" requires 0 parameter(s), passed 3!`

The [documentation](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrStr) specifies you are meant to pass 3 parameters for this function, contrary to the compile error above.

So how many parameters do I use for the NSIS function `StrStr`?

My code:

```
!include "StrFunc.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"


InstallDir  "abc"
Name        "def"        
OutFile     "def.exe"

Section
    ${StrStr} $R9 "How to find it" "find it"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: You might want to check the [complete example here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrFunc).

Comment: You have basically asked the same question 3 times now, why could you not edit your old question instead? Please just accept the answer posted by Matt Gibson and move on...

Answer (score 3):

Both the documentation and the compiler error are correct. `StrStr` takes both zero arguments, and three arguments, depending on context.  The first time it's seen, with no arguments, enables its use. Given the [example in the StrFunc](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrFunc) documentation, I'd try:

```
!include "StrFunc.nsh"
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

${StrStr} # Supportable for Install Sections and Functions

InstallDir  "abc"
Name        "def"        
OutFile     "def.exe"

Section
    ${StrStr} $R9 "How to find it" "find it"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: The links that you have posted no longer works, so there is no such example to consult...

Comment: @kdmin I can't see that page at the moment; I think there's an issue with their server. My answer references the page it does because that's where you're told that you need to enable the use of functions by declaring them, with no parameters, before you use them, with parameters: "Every command used in install sections and functions have to be called first before and out of any sections and functions, and without parameters." That's why I'm referencing that page. If you want to edit your link in to my answer for some reason, go ahead, but please leave my link in also.